# Jackson fasterxml ObjectMapper defaultPrettyPrintingWriter() method undefined replacement required

Tags: java, json, jackson, undefined

Migrating from Jackson 1.8.6 to 2.4.2, org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper has changed to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, and the following method is undefined for the new implementation: defaultPrettyPrintingWriter(), is there a replacement?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [ObjectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()).

Comment: Not found, please update this answer